# Unable to connect to Siebel Thick Client

Tags: siebel

I am unable to connect to the Thick Client.

I am getting the below mentioned error:

```
"The User ID or Password that u entered is incorrect".
```

But i am sure that the User ID and Password is correct because i use the same credentials to log into my thin client.

Comment: Seems that it is related to your app .cfg file. Are you sure that settings are correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Siebel always shows that error message if *anything* goes wrong while authenticating the user. *Anything* may be:

- Wrong username or password.
- Database not available.
- SRF file is corrupted.
- SRF file is out of date (specially, if there have been any changes to the tables and those changes are not compiled in your SRF).
- CFG file is not properly configured.
- Custom code on ApplicationStart produces an exception.
- ...

Doesn't matter what the problem is, Siebel will always tell you that the username/password are wrong.

You may find what your actual problem is by checking the latest **siebel.log** file, which should be placed in .../Client/log/, unless you changed its location.

As an alternative, you can keep reentering your username and password. Siebel gives you **3 attempts** to enter your credentials. The 2 first ones will show the "wrong password" message; however, the third and last attempt will show you the actual problem instead. At least, that's how it works in Siebel 7.8.

Anyway, it's better to just check the log file, since it will contain more information.

Answer (score 0):

1st check your password. Connect to database. Now test connection with thick client ODBC if you are able to successfully connect.And if this works then delete local spf file of user and also delete diccache.dat file created in bin directly.

Then try login. This resolved my issue.

You can refer Oracle support as well if this issue is replicated for you.
https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/SearchDocDisplay?_adf.ctrl-state=ntde4ixli_1004&_afrLoop=479412795573402